# Eliminar una columna de un array

Tags: php

Tengo este array de ejemplo:

```
Array           
(           
    [0] => Array            
        (           
            [id] => 45986           
            [fec_doc] => 31/10/2022         
            [importe] => 240            
        )           
            
    [1] => Array            
        (           
            [id] => 46260           
            [fec_doc] => 30/11/2022         
            [importe] => 400.00         
        )           
            
)
```

Quiero generar solamente un listado con **[fec_doc]** y **[importe]** usando un *foreach*:

```
foreach ($array as $fila) {
    fputcsv($archivo, $fila);
}
```

Pero cómo elimino toda la columna **[id]**? de tal forma que el array quede de esta manera?

```
Array           
(           
    [0] => Array            
        (           
            [fec_doc] => 31/10/2022         
            [importe] => 240            
        )           
            
    [1] => Array            
        (           
            [fec_doc] => 30/11/2022         
            [importe] => 400.00         
        )           
            
)
```

Comment: con un condicional que verifique primero si esa columna existe con isset(), y en caso afirmativo la eliminas con unset()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, si usas `unset` con un array, no es necesario verificar antes si la llave que quieres eliminar existe, ver al respecto [esta nota aportada por un usario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php#119711) en el Manual de PHP, y también [esta otra nota](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php#111576), otra cosa sería si se tratase de un objeto.

En segundo lugar, si quieres que `$array` quede modificado, debes **pasarlo por referencia**, si no lo haces, el `unset` no afectará al array en cuanto tal, sólo a la iteracción de `$fila` en tu contexto de lectura.

Por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($array as &$fila) {
    unset($fila['id']);    
    fputcsv($archivo, $fila);
}

var_dump($array);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fec_doc"]=>
    string(10) "31/10/2022"
    ["importe"]=>
    int(240)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fec_doc"]=>
    string(10) "30/11/2022"
    ["importe"]=>
    float(400)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal como dice masterguru en su comentario y dandole todos los creditos a el , el codigo finalmente quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```php
foreach ($array as $fila) {
    // Verificamos si existe esa columna
    if (isset($fila['id'])) {
        unset($fila['id']);
    }
    fputcsv($archivo, $fila);
}
```

Esto lo dejo como guia y ejemplo en codigo para la persona que tenga el mismo problema a futuro.

Comment: Yo verificaría que existe esa columna con un `if (isset($fila['id'])) { unset($fila['id']); }` en el mismo sitio donde has puesto el `unset()`. Más que nada por si acaso. Siempre es bueno evaluar si lo que se va a tratar existe antes.

Comment: Pues así lo hice y sigue apareciendo ['id']

Comment: @Puntay ¿Lo tienes exactamente como en la respuesta?  En mis pruebas sí me funcionó

Comment: @KatzeeDev he editado tu respuesta, ahora te habias dejado el fputcsv

Comment: Si, lo puse igual. Incluso puse un `echo` antes del `unset`, y si entra al `if`, pero por alguna razón no ejecuta el `unset`.

Comment: No sé si esa sea la causa, pero edité la pregunta.

Comment: @Puntay Ah, bueno, pensé que solo lo querias para el fputcsv... pues pasalo como referencia, es decir, `foreach ($array as &$fila) {` y de este modo el cambio quedará tambien en $array

Comment: Mil disculpas por no haber explicado ese detalle al inicio y mil gracias a todos.